# Как временно отключить полосу прокрутки ScrollView

Tags: java, android, прокрутка, scrollview

Приветствую ! Подскажите как справиться со следующей проблемой:
Есть TextView вложенный в ScrollView;
Пытаюсь скрыть полосу прокрутки

```
scrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Затем выполняю скролл

```
scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, iScrollY);
```

И все равно на экране отображается полоса прокрутки в момент перемещения; Как правильно скрыть полосу прокрутки ?

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.e(" new Runnable", "///////////////////////");
                iScrollY = contentNavigate.GetSuflerScrollPosition();
                ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
                scrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

                scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, iScrollY);

                scrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

            }
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: А если ещё это добавить: `view.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY)`?

Comment: Не помогло ... Может это прокрутка TextView а не ScrollView ?! Как проверить ?

Comment: Ну, колли у вас у TextView высота в wrap_content установлено, то на нём полосы прокрутки быть не должно.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте, также, выключать не только вертикальный, но и горизонтальный скролл.

```
scrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
scrollView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Не помогло ( Может есть еще вариант как то установить вид полосы прокрутки ?